# Always get ozone smell through basement windows, why?

Tags: atmospheric-science

We have a finished basement. The floor of the basement is about 5 feet below the outside ground level. The bottom of the windows is about 6 inches from the ground level and each measure 2' x 1' egress-style. The windows face due east.

If we leave one or both windows open for any period of time it smells like ozone comes in and settles in our living area. Other windows in the house don't do this ... and they are higher off the ground. Each time I Google ground-level ozone they are talking about general troposphere presence as a pollutant but nothing about the density maybe being higher than air.

We are about to install an ERV and it is convenient to draw air in from that side of the house. Now we are wondering if we should elevate the intake higher off the ground (and by how much) to avoid drawing in this smell.

EDIT: ERV is Energy Recovery Ventilator

We do fertilize with nitrogen but haven't applied anything to the yard for 4 months or more. We live near a busy highway and retail businesses:

[image: Our proximity to highway, busy streets, and commercial property]

Anyone have experience with this or subject matter experts out there? Your help is appreciated!

EDIT: As was suggested we are getting our VOC levels checked in the basement on Friday.

EDIT: Here are the TVOC and HCHO readings from in the house!

[image]

Comment: Have you tested the VOC levels in the basement? The open window might be a NOx source instead of an O3 source. In this case, the O3 is being generated in the basement because of a VOC that is reacting with the NOx (likely from proximity to heavy traffic and the nitrogen fertilizer). Other areas of the house may not accumulate enough VOCs for the ozone to be noticeable.

Comment: What's an ERV, please?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I ordered a device to measure the VOC levels... will let you know in a couple days!

Comment: @Gert sorry it stands for Energy Recovery Ventilator ... it is exchanges the heat and humidity from stale inside air with fresh air from outside (hence the concern).

Comment: Ozone smell is often confused with nitrogen oxide smell because both may be produced in high voltage discharge or as a product of UV irradiation. The first thing to clarify would be, why do you think you know it's ozone. My non-physical advice: don't drive yourself crazy about your environment. If you already live there, your are going to have to live with it anyway. The world is full of odd smells (I once lived on a farm, and pigs excrements can be as annoying as ozone smell in the long run, in my opinion). Strangely enough, the most hazardous things in life are those you can't smell or see.

Comment: @oliver your post made me smile... so true! I guess I don't know that it is ozone for sure... but it smells the same to me as approaching storms, plasma balls, slot cars, and other things that produce electric arcing. Is there a way to test for ozone like VOCs?

Comment: @JasonReskin: of course there is. But you have to ask yourself, whether it makes sense for you buying all sorts of meters for at least 500 bucks each, especially if it turns out that it wasn't this or that chemical. Maybe you can find somebody specialized in detecting pollutants and such. But keep in mind that there is a lot of wheeling and dealing with people's fears.

Comment: Some safety supply stores rent multi-gas sensors that they can configure to detect the chemicals you suspect (usually 5 or more sensors). They aren't very expensive to rent for a day and if you don't find the suspected chemicals, you can rent it again with different sensors. Check with several of your local industrial safety supply stores for sensor availability.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Attached are the readings. Interestingly, the HVOC and TVOC concentrations **outside are higher** than they are inside (WTH) ... but the CO2 concentration and particulates outside are less than half of the inside reading (good case for exchanging air).